# How to put editable text in static text paragraph in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox

What I'm trying to achieve is somewhat easy in web applications but I have been struggling to do it in WPF.

I want to load a paragraph of text in WPF and replace some of its specific words with editable textboxes. How can I do that?

What is the best strategy for getting this in a right a clean way?

**Update:**

Consider the following text. I want to display it in WPF and instead of the bold words put some textboxes.

> Do you know someone rich and famous? Is he confident, popular, and
>   joyful all **of** the time—the epitome **of** mainstream success?  Or,
>   **on** the other hand, is he stressed, having second thoughts about his life choices, and unsure about the meaning **of** his life?

Comment: Does it matter what his text is? Besides he is asking if there is a 'clean' way of doing it, you obviously could just throw a bunch of textboxes over a textblock but that is hardly satisfying.

Comment: Ryan Searle he has to show us sth then we can guide him to write a better code.since we don't know what is his code,how can we help him?!.and i should say there is no cleanest code for the question.we you compare code to other one,when there is code!

Comment: @Arashjo It is a simple text with no formatting whatsoever. I updated the question with a sample of the text. Regarding the code, honestly I have no idea how to program this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF and XAML, unlike HTML, are all about *data*.

The best way to think and reason about any XAML-based UI is to think about the *data* that you need to show and interact with.

In this case:

```
public class Word
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
}
```

would represent each of our words. Then you just need a List of these:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Word> Words { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        var editableWords = new[] { "on", "of" };

        var text = "Do you know someone rich and famous? Is he confident, popular, and joyful all of the time—the epitome of mainstream success? Or, on the other hand, is he stressed, having second thoughts about his life choices, and unsure about the meaning of his life?";

        this.Words =
            text.Split(' ')
                .Select(x => new Word
                {
                    Value = x,
                    IsEditable = editableWords.Contains(x.ToLower())
                })
                .ToList();
    }
}
```

Notice how I'm turning the text into a `List<Word>` and setting `IsEditable` where desired.

Now it's just a matter of using an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) to show these:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Words}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5,2,5,2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"
                             Visibility="{Binding IsEditable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Finally, set the [DataContext](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) to an instance of our ViewModel:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Notice that I'm not "touching" the UI in code at all, this is all just simple, simple properties and DataBinding.

Comment: Thank you so much HighCore, very elegant, but are you missing some part of the code in the example? Nothing is displayed in mine. Maybe a reference of something?

Comment: @Vahid make sure you set the Window's DataContext, like I do in code behind.

Comment: Thank you HighCore. Much respect.